# What and where is the file that contain tinymce.init in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

Im trying to find this file to change the original entity_encoding to this:

```
tinymce.init({
        ...
        entity_encoding : "raw"
});
```

Wordpress Version 3.6.1
TinyMCE Advanced Version 3.5.8

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can see the default settings in `/wp-includes/class-wp-editor.php` but you should not do this, don't modify `core` files, instead, you can use [tiny_mce_before_init](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/tiny_mce_before_init) hook and modify default settings in the callback function, using something like this

```
function myformatTinyMCE($in)
{
    $in['remove_linebreaks']=false;
    // more ...
    $in['theme_advanced_buttons4']='';
    $in['entity_encoding']= 'named'; // numeric/raw
    return $in;
}
```

Check [this example](http://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE) on Codex and [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/72941/avoid-converting-to-gt/72944#72944) may help you too.